# Conflict standart leaflet polygon and polilyne vs leaflet-dvf plugin

Tags: leaflet

I found some bug: if you are using leaflet-dvf plugin and want to draw standart leaflet polygon, you will get error in your browser's console like

```
Uncought RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

it will reference to leaflet-dvf.markers.min.js:6
TextFunctions._updatePath

it is 1838th string in here 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-dvf/0.2/leaflet-dvf.markers.js

How i can handle that error?